# docker-compose command giving error in kafka-zookeeper setup

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to synchronize kafka with zookeeper and for this I have two files kept on following path:

```
root@sevenos:/home/sevenos/Downloads/dockerrun# ls -l
total 80
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sevenos sevenos   816 Apr 24 17:12 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root     4096 Apr 24 15:35 scripts
-rwxrwxr-x 1 sevenos sevenos 55842 Apr 24 17:01 wait-for.sh
```

`wait-for.sh` is script taken from [Eficode](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for) which checks the availability of host and port and it is running fine locally.
The docker-compose file consist of following things:

```
    version: "2.1"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.0.0
    restart: always
    hostname: host
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - $PWD/scripts/security:/etc/kafka/secrets

    ports:
      - "32181:32181"

  kafka:
    image: modkafka
    hostname: host
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    command: sh -c '/subdir/wait-for.sh localhost:32181'
    volumes:
      - $PWD/scripts/security:/etc/kafka/secrets
      - ./subdir:/subdir
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "localhost:32181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

when i am triggering this compose file,kafka is getting triggered before and i am getting following error:

```
kafka        |   export KAFKA_LISTENERS
kafka        |   KAFKA_LISTENERS=$(cub listeners "$KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS")
kafka        | fi
kafka        | + [[ -z '' ]]
kafka        | + export KAFKA_LISTENERS
kafka        | cub listeners "$KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS"
kafka        | ++ cub listeners 'PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092"'
zookeeper    | sh: 1: ./wait-for: not found
zookeeper    | sh: 1: ./wait-for: not found
zookeeper    | sh: 1: ./wait-for: not found
kafka        | + KAFKA_LISTENERS='PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:29092"'
kafka        | 
kafka        | dub path /etc/kafka/ writable
kafka        | + dub path /etc/kafka/ writable
zookeeper exited with code 127
```

**UPDATE**

I have created new dockerfile for kafka mentioning following things:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0
RUN mkdir subdir
```

and build it in following way:

```
docker build -t modkafka .
```

Issue still persist.

Doing bash into modkafka results in following output:

```
root@sevenos:/home/sevenos/Downloads/dockerrun# docker exec -it kafka bash
root@sevenos:/# ls
bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv     sys  usr
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  subdir  tmp  var
root@sevenos:/# cd subdir
```

Updated docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.0.0
    restart: always
    hostname: host
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - $PWD/scripts/security:/etc/kafka/secrets

    ports:
      - "32181:32181"

  kafka:
    image: modkafka
    hostname: host
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    command: sh -c '/subdir/wait-for.sh localhost:32181'
    volumes:
      - $PWD/scripts/security:/etc/kafka/secrets
      - ./subdir:/subdir
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "localhost:32181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the script `wait-for.sh` into the containers.

For this you can mount a directory that contains the script inside the container. I recommend to move the `wait-for.sh` into a directory, just to be sure that the container doesn't access anything else from the hosts. Let's suppose that you move the script to `subdir`, then your compose file should look like this:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.0.0
    restart: always
    hostname: host
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - $PWD/scripts/security:/etc/kafka/secrets
    ports:
      - "32181:32181"
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0
    hostname: host
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - $PWD/scripts/security:/etc/kafka/secrets
      - ./subdir:/subdir
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    command: sh -c '/subdir/wait-for.sh localhost:32181'
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "localhost:32181"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Comment: will this "command" will come in kafka section or zookeeper section?

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf In the section where you use the script; in your case I see that you use it in zookeeper.

Comment: Ok..my bad maybe..but as kafka has to wait for zookeeper ,so its feels to me that this  should come in kafka section..your views?

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf in this case, YES, in the kafka section.

Comment: I have updated the docker-compose.yml file.Still error **kafka        | sh: 1: /subdir/wait-for.sh: not found**

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf have you added also a `volume`?

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf  `- ./subdir:/subdir`

Comment: If I take any folder existing in image of kafka such as usr and bind.will it work?

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean to say,when I attach console to container there are lots of folder in it.If I referenced anyone instead of subdir.will it work?

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf you can mount any directory from host into container

Comment: Issue still persist.constantin.Is there different way to trigger this script in command?

Comment: @UtkarshSaraf give me the new `docker-compose.yml` file that you have

Comment: I have updated it below and i am running this docker setup on lubuntu VM.Hope it doesnot effect